# allow prometheus to retrieve scrape targets using Zookeeper Serversets

Tags: apache-zookeeper, prometheus

I need to scrape targets using Prometheus using Zookeeper.
Here is the [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#%3Cserverset_sd_config%3E) of the article I referred, but I do not have any idea how to store serversets in Zookeeper. How can I do that?